# Java errors on Lotus Domino Designer Client 8.5.1

Tags: lotus-notes, designer

I have a clean install of Lotus Notes 8.5.1 (now with FP3) and I'm getting the following errors in Designer.  This is with a new database with a couple of forms and views.  I'm finding this is typical across all databases.

Is there something I need to install/configure etc.?  I'm not new to Notes, but I'm new to 8.5

> Description Resource Path Location Type
>   Cannot resolve plug-in: org.eclipse.core.runtime plugin.xml TestAgent.nsf line 9 Plug-in Problem
>   Cannot resolve plug-in: org.eclipse.ui plugin.xml TestAgent.nsf line 8 Plug-in Problem
>   Cannot resolve plug-in: com.ibm.commons plugin.xml TestAgent.nsf line 10 Plug-in Problem
>   Cannot resolve plug-in: com.ibm.commons.vfs plugin.xml TestAgent.nsf line 12 Plug-in Problem
>   Cannot resolve plug-in: com.ibm.commons.xml plugin.xml TestAgent.nsf line 11 Plug-in Problem
>   Cannot resolve plug-in: com.ibm.designer.runtime plugin.xml TestAgent.nsf line 15 Plug-in Problem
>   Cannot resolve plug-in: com.ibm.designer.runtime.directory plugin.xml TestAgent.nsf line 14 Plug-in Problem
>   Cannot resolve plug-in: com.ibm.jscript plugin.xml TestAgent.nsf line 13 Plug-in Problem
>   Cannot resolve plug-in: com.ibm.notes.java.api plugin.xml TestAgent.nsf line 20 Plug-in Problem
>   Cannot resolve plug-in: com.ibm.xsp.core plugin.xml TestAgent.nsf line 16 Plug-in Problem
>   Cannot resolve plug-in: com.ibm.xsp.core plugin.xml TestAgent.nsf line 21 Plug-in Problem
>   Cannot resolve plug-in: com.ibm.xsp.designer plugin.xml TestAgent.nsf line 18 Plug-in Problem
>   Cannot resolve plug-in: com.ibm.xsp.designer plugin.xml TestAgent.nsf line 22 Plug-in Problem
>   Cannot resolve plug-in: com.ibm.xsp.domino plugin.xml TestAgent.nsf line 19 Plug-in Problem
>   Cannot resolve plug-in: com.ibm.xsp.domino plugin.xml TestAgent.nsf line 23 Plug-in Problem
>   Cannot resolve plug-in: com.ibm.xsp.extsn plugin.xml TestAgent.nsf line 17 Plug-in Problem
>   Cannot resolve plug-in: com.ibm.xsp.extsn plugin.xml TestAgent.nsf line 24 Plug-in Problem
>   Cannot resolve plug-in: com.ibm.xsp.rcp plugin.xml TestAgent.nsf line 25 Plug-in Problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems this is down to the cache.ndk and workspace folders.  Delete these, and let the Notes client rebuild and all is well again.